# Using MAX date to JOIN tables and get column value

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I am trying to get the tracking number from a customers most recent order, but I am having trouble using MAX.

This just keeps returning nothing, even though I know table2 has values in there with dates. What's wrong with my query?

```
SELECT
    t1.Invoice_Num,
    t1.Tracking_Num
FROM
    table1 t1

JOIN
    table2 t2a on t1.Invoice_Num = t2a.Invoice_Num
JOIN (
    SELECT
        t2b.Invoice_Num,
        MAX(t2b.Invoice_Date) Last_Sale
    FROM
        table2 t2b
    WHERE
        t2b.Customer_Num = 'cust1'
    GROUP BY t2b.Invoice_Num
) LS
on t1.Invoice_Num = LS.Invoice_Num

--------------------------------------------------

Table1
+-------------+--------------+
| Invoice_Num | Tracking_Num |
+-------------+--------------+
| abc123      |     12345678 |
| def456      |     87654321 |
+-------------+--------------+

Table2
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Invoice_Num | Customer_Num | Invoice_Date |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| abc123      | cust1        | 10/25/2017   |
| def456      | cust1        | 10/24/2017   |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Desired output is -

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Invoice_Num | Tracking_Num |
+-------------+--------------+
| abc123      |     12345678 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

based on the most recent `Invoice_Date` of `cust1`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry What? how does this not follow that?

Comment: You should include your current and desire output

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza current ouput I said returns nothing. Desired output - getting the tracking number for `cust1` invoice with the max date. I'll add the clarification

Comment: Seems to work fine somehow: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77c57e/1

Comment: @Kenney Even when that query return the desire result. Isnt the correct query. You need perform the join using the `MAX(DATE)` as my answer show.

Comment: @Kenney Because I fix it. Check the last condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77c57e/8)

```
SELECT
    t1.Invoice_Num,
    t1.Tracking_Num
FROM table1 t1    
JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.Invoice_Num = t2.Invoice_Num
JOIN ( SELECT  MAX(t2b.Invoice_Date) Last_Sale
       FROM table2 t2b
       WHERE t2b.Customer_Num = 'cust1'
     ) LS
  ON t2.Invoice_Date = LS.Last_Sale
```

Be carefull because if multiple rows share the Last Sale you will get multiple rows.

Comment: try now. You dont need group by if are filtering for `cust1`

Comment: So, I'm not sure what's going on then, it's returning multiple rows, but `cust1` is not in those rows. I've got to do some more testing to see what the issue might be

Comment: FYI Juan, I made a typo in the schema: the 2nd row in table2 has 'def123' instead of 'def456'). Fixed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55eb18/1 (your solution still holds).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic alternative approach that can come in handy:

use `ORDER BY .. DESC` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT
       t1.Invoice_Num,
       t1.Tracking_Num
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 USING(Invoice_Num)
WHERE t2.Customer_Num = 'cust1'
ORDER BY t2.Invoice_Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce351/2)

Comment: I forgot when you filter a single row dont need any `GROUP BY` but be aware if multiple rows share the same maxdate you only will show one and not all the ties.